# jQuery unbind and bind keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, unbind

I have textbox with javacript function using `keypress`.

```
<input type="text" id="statusSheet"/>
```

JS

```
$('#statusSheet').keypress(function (e)
{
    if(e.which ==13)
    {
        $('#statusSheet').unbind('keypress');

        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "chkInfo",
            type: "POST",
            data:
            {
                statusSheet: statusSheet,
                dataID: dataID
            },
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (jsonStr)
            {
                $('#statusSheet').bind('keypress');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

When I try to press enter then first it will `unbind` the textbox until the ajax has been processed then revert it back to `bind` keypress.

After tried, the `unbind` is working good but when revert it back, there is no effect it still `unbind`.

Is it possible to unbind then bind the keypress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use [`.bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) again, you have to provide an event handler. That is an action to be done when the event is being fired. You did not provided one at your re-bind attempt so nothing happens when keypress is fired.

A solution for this is to write a function that handles your keypress event. If you want to rebind the keypress, just use that function as event handler.

```js
// this is called after each keypress in your element
function handleKeyPress(e) {
    console.log('hello');
    if(e.which ==13)
    {
        console.log('unbind key. Wait 5 seconds...');
        $('#statusSheet').unbind('keypress');

        // this timeout replaces the ajax call (similar behavior)
        window.setTimeout(function(){
          $('#statusSheet').bind('keypress', handleKeyPress); // rebind action.
        }, 5000);
    }
} 
// initial bind
$('#statusSheet').keypress(handleKeyPress);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="statusSheet"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).off("keypress", "#statusSheet").on("keypress", "#statusSheet", function (e) 
{
    if(e.which ==13)
    {
        $('#statusSheet').unbind('keypress');

        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "chkInfo",
            type: "POST",
            data:
            {
                statusSheet: statusSheet,
                dataID: dataID
            },
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (jsonStr)
            {
                $('#statusSheet').bind('keypress');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't bind an event handler back to your element. You could do this like this:

```
let $statusSheet = $('#statusSheet');
let onKeyPress = (e) => {
    if(e.which == 13)
    {
        $statusSheet.unbind('keypress');

        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "chkInfo",
            type: "POST",
            data:
            {
                statusSheet: statusSheet,
                dataID: dataID
            },
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (jsonStr)
            {
                 $statusSheet.keypress(onKeyPress);
            }
        }
    }
}
$statusSheet.keypress(onKeyPress);
```